# Android Multiple Views

Tags: android, layout, scroll

I am trying to make an app that will have multiple screens, and I want to be able to swipe left and right to go back and forth from screen to screen. Basically like how you go through pi ctures in the gallery, but mine won't just be pictures. Any tutorials or a suggestion on what type layout I should use.. TIA

Comment: I am going to try the Horizontal Scroll View first, since it doesn't require all of the animation stuff. If that doesn't fit my needs, I'll go to the ViewFlipper. Thanks. Sorry I can't accept both of your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). If you want it to snap, you will probably have to write some code that sets the position of the scrollview correctly either on up touchevents, and/or intercepting those events to a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) with [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) to catch flings specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this effect using ViewFlipper...

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply gestures. This link could help you which explains the same you need:

http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/swipe-fling-to-switch-between-activities-t15602.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [Gallery View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) with an adapter that returns the views you want to scroll with. But it's going to be a pain laying out the views...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the launch screen has.

http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/

also:

[Flingable Tab Host](http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/beta/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/widget/FlingableTabHost.java?spec=svn117&r=117)

also:

[Android Snapping HorizontalScrollView](http://www.matt-reid.co.uk/blog_post.php?id=62)

and finally:

[Horizontal Pager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager/blob/master/README.markdown)